# What is ?ngModel?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When creating a directive in angular I believe you can use `require: '^ngModel'` to look back to a parent directive's model.  However, does `require: '?ngModel'` look for the first model in the current directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The required name can be prefixed with:
>
> `?` – Don't raise an error if the controller isn't found
>   `^` – Look for the controller on parent elements, not just on the local scope

[ng-newsletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html)

Comment: I would have said: ? - Won't raise an error if the _controller_ isn't found.

Comment: If you're quoting something, can you add a link to the source?

Comment: CD..: you're welcome :) @Reboog711 http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html